# How to restart service is running in docker without restart docker image or docker image stop working

Tags: git, docker, .net-core

My situation is i want to make my docker image pull code from git when run "docker run ..."

build and make it run again in docker container without restart docker container.

i try to use `kill $(ps aux | grep "filename.dll" | awk "{print $2}")` to stop "dotnet filename.dll"

is running previously but it make my docker stop working.

---

Update
I know this process is a bad practice but my customer need it then i ask here.
I already know best practice clean make it clean image.
Please understand me.

Comment: I  tried to run docker exec -it <container id> <shell> to stop it and it wont work. Why i get -1  what wrong with my question ?

Comment: Generally you need to run `git pull` on the host, `docker build` to build a new image, and then `docker run` a new container off the new image.  Deleting and recreating containers for code updates like this is extremely routine.

Comment: @DavidMaze I know that process many blog post that i read before they do  like you tell me. But my customer require to do that then i ask here the way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer here is: Don't.
You are trying to work around one of the basic intents for using containers, which is fast start and stop times. Trying to avoid removing and creating instances of a container for code updates isn't something you should worry about. If your image is pulling code rather than being an updated image, your image doesn't necessarily fulfill the purpose of an image in the first place. Images are meant to be updated to improve or update applications.
I highly recommend getting comfortable with the workflow rather than trying to circumvent it.

Comment: Yes i know and i understand about it. And i cant circumvent  a customer requirement too. I i can control all of it i wont do like that i ask.